# Laravel web push notifications

Tags: laravel, push-notification, pusher

I have a user registration system.I want to send web notification to specific user when an admin approve that user account.email already  send to users. I tried using this pusher.data also inserted into notification table.but always notifiable_id value shows as "1".[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U24mH.png)

this is the code for notification class

```
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
class UserRegistrationCompleteNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    private $details;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($details,$email)
    {
        $this->details= $details;
        $this->email = $email;
    }
    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail','database'];
    }
    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $notifiable->email = $this->email;
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->greeting($this->details['greeting'])
            ->subject('【M&A】 会員登録のご案内')
            ->line($this->details['body1'])
            ->line($this->details['body2'])
            ->line($this->details['body3'])
            ->line($this->details['body4'])
            ->line($this->details['body5'])
            ->line($this->details['body6'])
            ->line($this->details['body7'])
            ->line($this->details['body8'])
            ->line($this->details['body9'])
            ->line($this->details['body10'])
            ->line($this->details['thanks']);
    }
    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add your where you trigger the notification please? Are you using the `Notification` facade or the `notify` method, or how are you sending the notifications?

Comment: @DelenaMalan I'm using Notification facade

Comment: Could you add that part of your code please?

Comment: ```
public function registerComplete(Request $request)
    {
            if (!empty($_POST['user_id'])) {
                 $user = User::first();
                Notification::send($user, new UserRegistrationCompleteNotification($details, $email));
               return redirect('/login')->with('success', 'ユーザー登録していただき、ありがとうございます。');
        } 
}
```

Comment: So you're always sending the notification to the first user (`User::first()`)? (Also, please add your code to your question and not as a comment)